# How to cover all the below lines in Junit/Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, code-coverage, junit4

I tried mocking the JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate ,but that didn't cover whatever is inside

new Employee(.......);

Please let me know is there any way to cover those lines inside new Employee(...)?

```
public List<Employee> findByCustIdAndType(long Id, String type) 
    {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(SQL.getEmployee(Id, type),
                (rs, rowNum) -> new Employee(rs.getLong("CUSTOMER_ID"), 
                                             rs.getLong("ANCHOR_CUSTOMER_ID") ,
                                             rs.getString("SEGMENT"), 
                                             rs.getDate("END_TS")));
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using Mockito to capture the lambda, which is a `RowMapper<Employee>`.  Then invoke it with a mock `ResultSet` set up to return the expected values so the returned `Employee` can be asserted.  Here's an example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmployeeDAOTest {
    private static final long CUSTOMER_ID = 1;
    private static final long ANCHOR_CUSTOMER_ID = 2;
    private static final String SEGMENT = "A";
    private static final Date END_TS = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());

    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeDAO dao;

    @Mock   
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Mock   
    private ResultSet resultSet;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<RowMapper<Employee>> rowMapperCaptor;

    @Before
    public void prepareTest() throws SQLException {
        when(resultSet.getLong("CUSTOMER_ID")).thenReturn(CUSTOMER_ID);
        when(resultSet.getLong("ANCHOR_CUSTOMER_ID")).thenReturn(ANCHOR_CUSTOMER_ID);
        when(resultSet.getString("SEGMENT")).thenReturn(SEGMENT);
        when(resultSet.getDate("END_TS")).thenReturn(END_TS);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws SQLException {
        dao.findByCustIdAndType(0, null);

        verify(jdbcTemplate).query(anyString(), rowMapperCaptor.capture());
        RowMapper<Employee> rowMapper = rowMapperCaptor.getValue();
        Employee employee = rowMapper.mapRow(resultSet, 1);
        assertEquals(CUSTOMER_ID, employee.getCustomerId());
        assertEquals(ANCHOR_CUSTOMER_ID, employee.getAnchorCustomerId());
        assertEquals(SEGMENT, employee.getSegment());
        assertEquals(END_TS, employee.getEndTs());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Perfect.
Could you please explain how this works like what get called after what bit clearly.
And also how the captor works?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but just add breakpoints to see the order of invocation.  The captor allows capturing the parameter(s) of a method of an injected mock - in this case a RowMapper defined by a lambda.  The captor is populated when verify() is invoked.  After that, the captured parameter can be accessed and used as needed.  In this case, it's a RowMapper so it's mapRow() method is invoked so that the result (an `Employee`) can be asserted.  Google for tutorials and examples.